# Multi link event in image map doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make multi link in single image with image map.
I want add some event when user hover the link with this script

```
$("#gt1").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).append($("<div id='mouse' class='gtcon'><span>Hello 1</span></div>"));
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("div:last").remove();
    }
);
```

But is not working. any suggestion?
Here my complete script. [**http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/6t9gL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/6t9gL/)

Comment: you want to add a `<div>` inside an `<area>` ?

Comment: I am so sorry, I am totally blind with javascript.
can you please help me make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to add a `<div>` inside an `<area>` (`this`), which makes no sense.

But I think you want this :

```
$("#gt1").hover(
    function () {
        $(document.body).append($("<div id='mouse' class='gtcon'><span>Hello 1</span></div>"));
    },
    function () {
        $("div:last").remove();
    }
);
```

This effectively makes the pretty bubbles you probably want.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TykTz/)

As noticed by gvee, you can reduce repetitions. For example :

```
var texts = [null,'hello 1', 'hello 2'];
$(".pin").hover(
    function () {
        $(document.body).append($("<div id='mouse' class='gtcon'><span>"+texts[this.id.slice(-1)]+"</span></div>"));
    },
    function () {
        $("#mouse").remove();
    }
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dyfAj/)

Comment: Why not `$('.pin').hover(...` ? In your demo you are repeating code... I assume that this is because of content changes? If so I would consider storing the display text in a custom data attribute and grabbing that instead... http://jsfiddle.net/TykTz/2/

Comment: ...also, why not change the last part to `$('#mouse').remove();`? Bit more "robust" in case there is anything else appending `div` elements to the body....